# How can I define a specific type for a mutable variable?

Tags: types, ocaml, mutable, ref

I'm a beginner in OCaml. I want to compile this code, but I get an error.

```ml
type pointeur_de_code = int;;
type environnement = int;;
type mlvalue =
 | Ml1 of int
 | Ml2 of pointeur_de_code * environnement;;
let (accu:mlvalue) = ref 0;;
```

> This expression has type int ref but an expression was expected of type mlvalue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a variant type like `mlvalue` you define constructors for values of the type. You have a constructor named `Ml1` that takes an `int` and makes a value. And you have a constructor named `Ml2` that takes two `int`s and makes a value.

To make a value of the type, you need to include the constructor.

In addition, the type of your `accu` can't be `mlvalue`. It must be `mlvalue ref`, which is a different type.

```
let accu : mlvalue ref = ref (Ml1 0)
```

(Note that you don't need to supply the type of `accu`. OCaml will infer the type for you.)